# Can't boot Galaxy S I9000 into recovery mode to install Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I believe my volume up button is not working on my galaxy s i9000, and I'm trying to get it into recovery mode.

Right now the phone is bricked, so I can still get it into download mode.  So at the moment I have CWM on it, though that seems pretty useless if I can't get the phone into recovery mode.

How in the world can I get the phone to boot into recovery mode?

Comment: Is this related to Ubuntu?..

Comment: Have you tried **`adb reboot recovery`** ?

Comment: yeah right now I'm trying to put ubuntu touch on the phone

Comment: and the problem with adb is before this I had a put a corrupted recovery on the phone that bricked the phone, so after that I put on CWM and that worked, but I can't turn the phone on normally to use the adb commands.

Comment: There are several questions over at our sister site of [Android.SE] which you might wish to consult: [Galaxy S GT-I9000: how to fix boot to recovery with Volume up+Power?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32637/16575) coming close, and [Cannot boot into recovery (Samsung Galaxy S)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/48417/16575) seemingly describing exactly your issue (letting the boot-loop part aside). For more, please check [these 21 related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=galaxy+i9000+recovery+is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 1):

For recovery, hold volume up and home then press power. To enable the Ubuntu Touch Preview to be installed, you need to format the /system partition before selecting to install ROM. Your /sdcard should remain intactFailing to format first will brick the phone (my first mistake!) but the right button combination should do the trick. If the phone freezes, remove the battery to kill it and try again.

Comment: The problem is that my volume up key does not work, that is what I am trying to get around. And because i bricked by phone I can't use any adb functions

Comment: If the volume down still works, boot into 'Download Mode' and try the following (replacing the steps that download the Nexus ROMs with the i9000 ones). Good luck!    https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install     https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Answer (score 0):

Try flashing it back to Original stock ROM using Odin.

Use the link below
[link](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f777/upgrade-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000-firmware-using-odin-flash-too-1605005/)